# Validate decimal and integer values by looping through list of dynamic columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I was tasked to validate the decimal and integer values of the columns from a list of tables. I have around 10-12 tables having different column names.
I created a lookup table which has the table name and the column names of decimal and integer as shown below. for example 'Pricedetails' and 'Itemdetails' tables have many columns of which only the ones mentioned in the Lookup table are required.

**lkpTable**

| TableName | requiredcolumns |
| --- | --- |
| Pricedetails | sellingPrice,RetailPrice,Wholesaleprice |
| Itemdetails | ItemID,Itemprice |

**Pricedetails**

| Priceid | Mafdate | MafName | sellingPrice | RetailPrice | Wholesaleprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2020-01-01 | Americas | 25.00 | 43.33 | 33.66 |
| 02 | 2020-01-01 | Americas | 43.45 | 22.55 | 11.11 |
| 03 | 2021-01-01 | Asia | -23.00 | -34.00 | 23.00 |

**Itemdetails**

| ItemID | ItemPrice | Itemlocation | ItemManuf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 45.11 | Americas | SA |
| 02 | 25.00 | Americas | SA |
| 03 | 35.67 | Americas | SA |

I have created a stored procedure with table name as input parameter, and able to pull the required column names of the tables (input parameter) from the lookup table and store that resultset into a table variable, below is the code.

```
declare @resultset Table
(
id INT identity(1,1),
tablename varchar(200) ,
ColumnNames varchar(max)
)

declare @tblname varchar(200),@sql varchar(max),@cols varchar(max),
INSERT INTO @resultset
select tablename,ColumnNames
from lkptable where tablename ='itemdetails'
select @cols =  ColumnNames from @resultset;
select @tblname = TableName from @resultset;
----- Split the comma separated columnnames 
Create table ##splitcols
(
ID int identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50)
)
Insert into ##splitcols
select value from string_split(@cols,',') 
set @sql = 'select ' +@cols + ' from ' +@tblname
--print (@cols)
exec (@sql)
select * from ##splitcols
```

On executing the above code i get the below result sets, similarly what ever table name i provide i can get the required columns and its relevant data, now i am stuck at this point on how to validate whether the columns are decimal or int. I tried using while loop and cursor to pass the Name value from **Resultset2**, to the new dynamic query, somehow i don't find any way on how to validate.

| ItemID | ItemPrice |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 45.11 |
| 02 | 25.00 |
| 03 | 35.67 |

**Resultset2**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | ItemID |
| 02 | ItemPrice |

Answer (score 0):

you can validate in this way

```
insert into @splitcols values (1.1),(1.11)

select case when (t * 100)%10 = 0 then 1 else 0 end as valid from @splitcols
```

Similarly for number/integer

Answer (score 0):

You can generate one giant `UNION ALL` query using dynamic SQL, then run it.

Each query would be of the form:

```sql
SELECT
  TableName = 'SomeTable',
  ColumnName,
  IsInt
FROM (
    SELECT 
    [Column1] = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ROUND([Column1], 0) <> [Column1] THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN 'All ints' ELSE 'Not All ints' END,
    [Column2] = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ROUND([Column2], 0) <> [Column2] THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN 'All ints' ELSE 'Not All ints' END
    FROM SomeTable
) t
UNPIVOT (
  ColumnName FOR IsInt IN (
    [Column1], [Column2]
  )
) u
```

The script is as follows

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG('
SELECT
  TableName = ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ',
  ColumnName,
  IsInt
FROM (
    SELECT ' + c.BeforePivotCoumns + '
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
) t
UNPIVOT (
  ColumnName FOR IsInt IN (
    ' + c.UnpivotColumns + '
  )
) u
', '
UNION ALL '
  )
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN lkpTable lkp ON lkp.TableName = t.name
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      BeforePivotCoumns = STRING_AGG(CAST('
    ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ROUND(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', 0) <> ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN ''All ints'' ELSE ''Not All ints'' END'
        AS nvarchar(max)), ','),
      
      UnpivotColumns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(c.name), ', ')
      
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN STRING_SPLIT(lkp.requiredcolumns, ',') req ON req.value = c.name
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
) c;

PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e58cc747c3758ac45aac9d1b3e17c27)

If you are on an older version of SQL Server then you can't use `STRING_AGG` and instead you need to hack it with `FOR XML` and `STUFF`.

```sql
DECLARE @unionall nvarchar(100) = '
UNION ALL ';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = STUFF(
  (SELECT @unionall + '
SELECT
  TableName = ' + QUOTENAME(t.name, '''') + ',
  ColumnName,
  IsInt
FROM (
    SELECT ' + STUFF(c1.BeforePivotCoumns.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + '
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
) t
UNPIVOT (
  ColumnName FOR IsInt IN (
    ' + STUFF(c2.UnpivotColumns.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') + '
  )
) u'
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      lkp.TableName
    FROM lkpTable lkp
) lkp ON lkp.TableName = t.name

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      ',
    ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN ROUND(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ', 0) <> ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' THEN 1 END) = 0 THEN ''All ints'' ELSE ''Not All ints'' END'
    FROM lkpTable lkp2
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(lkp2.requiredcolumns, ',') req
    JOIN sys.columns c ON req.value = c.name
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
      AND lkp2.TableName = lkp.TableName
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) c1(BeforePivotCoumns)

CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
       ', ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
    FROM lkpTable lkp2
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(lkp2.requiredcolumns, ',') req
    JOIN sys.columns c ON req.value = c.name
    WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
      AND lkp2.TableName = lkp.TableName
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
) c2(UnpivotColumns)

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, LEN(@unionall), '');


PRINT @sql;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e1f48fb2551da1fbee0765a004ce3b26)

Comment: I tried running the script, but it throws error for String_AGG saying, it is not valid function, i am using SQL server 2016 Sp-2.

Comment: OK have added solution for older versions also